# Trouble using $_POST across files with XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, post

I want to process form input into a MYSQL database but I am having trouble getting other files to recognize data in the _POST array and keep getting the typical "Undefined index" error.
My form:

```
    <?php
    $category = '';
    $item = '';
    // Check if form is posted
    if (isset($_POST['item'])){
        // Declare POST'd values into variables
        $category = $_POST['Category'];
        $item = $_POST['item'];
    }
    ?>
    <!-- Item Input form -->
    <form id='additem' method='post' action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Item</legend>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for='Category'>Category: </label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='Category' list='categories' value='<?php $category;?>' /></td>
                <datalist id='categories'>
                    <option value='Protein'>
                    <option value='Produce'>
                    <option value='Baked Goods'>
                    <option value='Dry/Canned'>
                    <option value='Household'>
                </datalist>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><label for='item'>Name: </label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='item' value='<?php $item;?>' /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td></td><td><input type='Submit' value='Submit' /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

When I use $_POST in this file, it works perfectly fine but when I try to use it in another file, process.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['Category'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_POST['item'];
?>
```

it gives:
Notice: Undefined index: Category in E:\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\Website\process.php on line 3
Notice: Undefined index: item in E:\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\Website\process.php on line 5

Now I know my _POST array is not empty, because I can access it within my original form file. If I change the form action to "process.php" it works, but also automatically takes me to that page. What I want is for process.php to send data to my database while the form returns to its own page ready for more input. I have even literally copy and pasted the code from that example into files and attempted to run those, but I get similar errors so I think it might be an issue with XAMPP/Apache.

To address this, I have also tried [this](http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/) but post_max_size was already set to 8M, and as per another post I saw somewhere I added 'variables_order = "EGPCS"' in the line below. Still I am getting the same undefined index.

Is there something wrong with my code? Is it XAMPP/Apache? I have tried fresh installing XAMPP, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $_POST array will not be accessible on all pages.
As much as I have understood your problem , You are trying to access $_POST array on some other file , and this can only be used in this file or the file you post to.
You need to use [SESSION](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) in order to use these values

#### After POST Assign your values like this

```
$_SESSION["Category"] = $_POST['Category'];
```

Then on any other page just use
`session_start();` on the top of page and then print your variable like

```
echo "Selected Category is " . $_SESSION["Category"] . ".<br>";
```

Comment: Cookies can also be used but if any person had disabled their cookies in their browser then it will cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! It occurred to me that I might have to use session variables, but I was confused because in the guide that I linked above he didn't use the process.php in his form action and the post variables just seemed to magically send to the second file and I couldn't figure out why mine wouldn't just do the same. Now I see he must have made a mistake and didn't fix it for the guide...

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the location or file in the action attribute of form element. The file specified in the action attribute can have the values of the form in &_POST[] global array. To access the values across multiple page you should use the cookies

Comment: As I said above, I tried using the location in the action attribute but that brought me away from my form to the process.php page, which I didn't want. Instead of using cookies, I think I will use the session array as above.

Answer (score 0):

Put check on

> category

as you are only checking the

> item

in array and if category is not present in array then it will give undefined index error so try the following ways

```
$category = '';
$item = '';
 if (isset($_POST['item']) && isset($_POST['Category'])){
    // Declare POST'd values into variables
    $category = $_POST['Category'];
    $item = $_POST['item'];
}
```

or if you want you can check them in different conditions

```
$category = '';
$item = '';
if (isset($_POST['item'])){
    // Declare POST'd values into variables
    $item = $_POST['item'];
}

if (isset($_POST['Category'])){
    // Declare POST'd values into variables
    $category = $_POST['Category'];
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but it does seem to be a good way to check that the form was fully completed upon submission, thanks!